# Strategies for generating pairwise ranking requests - efficeintly generating the best model inputs for Bradley–Terry model or Plackett-Luce

Tags: probability, predictive-models, paired-data

I'm using the python library `choix`, which is great for converting pairwise comparisons (or a few other subset ranking metrics, top-1 of n and ranked subset) into global rankings using either the Bradley–Terry model or Plackett-Luce.

I want to present images to users and get their arbitrary aesthetic judgement on them, which clearly isn't going to be consistently ordered, and was wondering if there were any good strategies for this.

I've tried iteratively going through all of the dataset and making sure each input gets at least `minimum-global-wins` wins for `top-1 of n` and `pairwise` inputs which does flatten the distribution of the global scores very fast - but am not convinced this is a good ordering so much as a fast one.